# How to get the day of every Monday in a month for a given date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-docs

Let me start with the following example:

```
A1 =DATE(2015, 6, 1)
A2 =A1 + 7
```

**Result**

```
6/8/2015 
6/15/2015
6/22/2015
6/29/2015
7/6/2015
7/13/2015
7/20/2015
```

Good result, but I'd like to get more formatted sequence like:

```
A1 =TEXT(DAY(DATE(2015, 6, 1)), "dd")
A2 =TEXT(DAY(A1 + 7), "dd")
```

**Expected**:

```
01 08 15 22 29 06 13 20
```

**Result**:

```
31 05 10 15 20 25 30 04
```

Why and how to fix it?

PS: I'm using Google Stylesheets

Comment: You added tag "excel" tag to your question: could you please clarify - are you looking for Excel Worksheet solution? Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stumbled into a common mistake. Your current formula for A1 gets the day of the 01-Jun-2015. This is now an integer, not a date; specifically *1*. It should not be using the *dd* format mask. Either discard the `DAY` function or use *00* as the format mask.

```
=TEXT(DAY(DATE(2015, 6, 1)), "00")
=TEXT(DATE(2015, 6, 1), "dd")
```

Your `=TEXT(DAY(A1 + 7), "dd")` similarly confuses a date with an integer representing the day of the month. While this will work for a single month (by sheer coincidence due to the similarity to the month to Jan-1900) it will cause problems with the next month; e.g. Jun-2015 has 30 days and Jan-1900 has 31 days.

Best to start a date in A1 and expand that date according to the number of rows you fill down.

```
=TEXT(DATE(2015, 6, 1+(ROW(1:1)-1)*7), "dd")
```

BTW, Excel thinks *01-Jun-2015* is *42,156*, not *1*.

Comment: More thanks! 
Could you please tell me how to make a horizontal filling?

Comment: `=TEXT(DATE(2015, 6, 1 + (COLUMN(A1:B1) - 1) * 7), "dd")` Thanks!